# displaying image in laravel (4.2) blade from a php file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm new to laravel 4.2 and I'm thinking how can I display an image that is being generated from a php file.

here is my php file (capt.php)

```
<?php
        session_start();
        $code=rand(100000,999999);
        $_SESSION["code"]=$code;
        $im = imagecreatetruecolor(50, 24);
        $bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 189, 195, 199); //background color blue
        $fg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);//text color white
        imagefill($im, 0, 0, $bg);
        imagestring($im, 5, 5, 5,  $code, $fg);
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
        header('Content-type: image/png');
        imagepng($im);
        imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

it just generates an image of a random generated number.

I just put the php file under the App and I'm calling it to my blade as

```
{{ HTML::image(URL::to('capt.php')) }}
```

Comment: Specify the link to the image generated not to the script that generates it, if you save the image as img/yourimage.jpg, then you do {{ HTML::image(URL::to('img/yourimage.jpg')) }}

Comment: thanks! will try it out! :)